# Makefile for compiling Allegro5 c program

Tags: c, makefile, allegro5

I wrote a little game in c using Allegro 5 library. I need to compile and run it on a generic linux environment, so i try to do a makefile for easy compiling it.

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -c
EFLAGS =
EOPTION = `pkg-config --cflags --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_acodec-5.0` -lm
OBJFOLD = objectfiles
SOURCE = #all my source codes.
OBJECT = #all my object files.
EXC = Foo

all: $(SOURCE) $(EXC)

$(EXC): $(OBJECT)
    gcc $(EFLAGS) -o $(EXC) $(OBJECT) $(EOPTION) 

$(OBJFOLD)/%.o: %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJFOLD)/%.o: libraries/%.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

It works fine on my computer in which i installed Allegro 5 library, but i need it works on a Linux Os just running the make files (so without installing Allegro 5 every time). My project folder's struct is:

```
- Project
    -allegro5
    -bin
    -fonts
    -images
    -include
    -libraries
    -objectfiles
    -sounds
```

So, I added to $(OBJFOLD)/%.o target's instruction the option '-Iallegro5/include' but when I try to run the makefile, it return:

```
$ make -f Makefile
gcc -Wall -c Main.c -o objectfiles/Main.o -Iallegro5/include
In file included from allegro5/include/allegro5/internal/alconfig.h:35:0,
                 from allegro5/include/allegro5/base.h:50,
                 from allegro5/include/allegro5/allegro.h:26,
                 from Main.c:3:
allegro5/include/allegro5/platform/almngw32.h:23:20: fatal error: direct.h: No such file or directory
 #include "allegro5/platform/alplatf.h"
                                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

I think I am on a totally wrong way, so can someone help me?
I'm now working on a Cygwin environment on my Windows pc, and i download my "allegro5" folder from [here](https://www.allegro.cc/files/).
I prefer to solve it using a makefile.

Comment: Ok, i edited the post too much time, but this is the problem user2500758 correctly solved.

Comment: Now i have all my .o files, but when i try to compile them, the gcc compiler give me the error "/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found", so i try to substitute the 'pkg-config ...' command with '-Iallegro5/include -lallegro', but it not work too. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be -Iallegro5/include??
(capital i, not small L)

Comment: Again... :(. Anyway, it might be that 'direct.h', which is included by one of the header files of allegro, does not actually exist in a standard directory. Try to locate it and add its location as well by '-Ipath/to/direct.h'

Comment: Yes, sorry, i changed folder's name to easy write the problem.
Mhhhh, now i try!

Comment: Mhhhh, my wrong, i use the windows allegro5 library, my fault, i change the question =)

Comment: Looks like direct.h is a Mingw header and not one from Allegro. http://angband.oook.cz/forum/showthread.php?t=6446 This guy solved it by removing the '#include <direct.h>' completely. As a last resort, you could try to edit the allegro headers to remove these lines. See if that works

Comment: Oh... okay I saw your comment write after I posted mine. Hope you best of luck with fixing your problem :)

Comment: Ohhh, wonderful... now i have one more problem, can u help me just one more time? *_*

Comment: What's that? I'll gladly help

Comment: I wrote it in the comment of my question =)

Comment: I cant seem to comment on the original post for some reason. The problem is that pkg-config is not installed in Cygwin. But even if you installed it it wouldnt work, cause the allegro info packages for pkg-config to work are missing. So, the only way to get it to work is to hand-craft a large list of all the include directories and the allegro libraries and pass them directly into gcc. And that is not worth your time. Is there a specific reason why you must use Cygwin? If it's easy, try CodeBlocks: https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Code::Blocks_and_Allegro_5

Comment: I use Code::Blocks for write and run my game, but I must send it to my prof, and he wants a Makefile for compile and run it on a linux environment. I also try to use cbp2make, but it doesn't work <<

Comment: If he does have a linux environment, then he should have pkg-config with the required allegro5 package files. So, pkg-config should work for him. Telling your professor about this would most likely help without hurting anybody.